# I lost all connections in Hub when I'm adding ConnectionId to group

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm working on my SignalR Hub.

I want to add `Context.ConnectionId` to specific group when `OnConnectedAsync()` was triggered.

When I write something like this:

```
public override Task OnConnectedAsync()                                                                 
{                                                                                                       
    // succeeded adding ConnectionId to User in my cache                                                              
                                                                                                       
    if (succeeded)                                                                                      
    {                                                                                                   
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, user.Id1);
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, user.Id2);   
    }                                                                  
}
```

I lost all my connections on the hub. When I deleted this `AddToGroupAsync()` part, everything works fine (connections exist but not in groups).

Why is it that when I'm adding `ConnectionId` using `AddToGroupAsync()`, I lose all connections in that simple method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didnt found a solution for that problem so i will answer here.

While you triggering the method:

```
await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, user.Id1);
```

You need to check, if `user.Id1` is not null. When it is it seems like SignalR Hub cant handle it and he deletes the connection from the hub.

Before adding connection id to group just check, if string is not null:

```
if (user.Id1 != null) // or string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Id1)
{
    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, user.Id1);
}
```